# Prolog - Merging Symbols (or Terms?)

Tags: prolog

*(Pardon if my terminology is wrong... I'm new to Prolog.)*

Suppose you have a series of symbols appearing in some unknown number of predicates.

```
f1(a, b, c, d).
f2(b, b, c).
...
fn(b, d, e).
```

Later--at runtime--you realize that terms `a` and `b` are the same, and you wish to merge them or replace one of them with the other. In other words, I would like to either:

- Make `a = b`
- Replace all instances of `a` with `b`
- Replace `a` and `b` with a new symbol (made through gensym/2)
- ...or anything else that accomplishes this

... where I do not know which predicates use these terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atoms that start with upper case letters are variables. The first step then is to use `A` and `B`. If at some point you decide two variables are actually equal, you just say it `A = B`. The process of stating logically that one thing = another is "unification".

e.g.

```
veryDifferentOrTheSame(A,B) :- veryDifferent(A,B).
veryDifferentOrTheSame(A,B) :- A = B.
```

Of course, unification won't always work. `a(X) = b(X)` will fail.

This all implies that when the code was written, you knew that you weren't sure A=B.

You can also dynamically assert clauses at runtime. Declaring a clause as dynamic and using assera or assertz.

But if you state:

```
iOwn(goldfish).
iOwnFish :- iOwn(fish).
```

and then want to make that work by saying "in my universe fish = goldfish", then you're in strange territory.

Comment: The simple use of lowercase `a` and `b` gives what are called "atoms" in Prolog, which are a kind of constant like strings but stored in a special table so that they can be stored there once and referenced everywhere in the program by lookup.  [This approach is a legacy of the early implementations of Prolog where memory was a scarce resource.]  Most Prologs have ways to create a new atom that doesn't start with lowercase alphabetic characters, but changing the text of atom table entries that already exist is not allowed.